# How to assign a value to a dynamic variable using eval?

Tags: javascript

I got the dynamic variable name doing

```
varname = "data" + newid + "['" + name + "']";
```

I would like to assign a value to the dynamic variable. I tried this

```
eval(varname) = value;
```

but it doesn't work. What do I need to do in order to assign a value to the dynamic variable?

Comment: Don't use friggin' dynamic variables. Use objects. In particular, `data[newid][name]`, and that works with assignment too.

Comment: actually I have inserted many jsons through php into my javascript with names in the format datafirst,datasecond etc so in my javascript code im trying to decide which variable amongst them I should manipulate

Comment: Then don't generate data like that. Generate a JSON literal where the `newid` is also abstracted out.

Comment: It's fine to use it for educational purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data1 = { a: 200 };
var newid = 1;
var name = "a";

var varname = "data"+newid+"['"+name+"']";
var value = 3;
eval(varname + "=" + value); // change data1['a'] from 200 to 3
```

<sub>Having said that, `eval` is evil. Are you really sure you need to use dynamic variables?</sub>

Comment: For my purpose I would like to assign a value to the dynamic variable not get its value.How do I do it?

Comment: @juria_roberts: I see, use `eval(varname + "=" + value)` then. Also consider using @Quentin's solution instead of using dynamic variables.

Comment: Can I use eval to emulate `out` parameters, or passing of parameters by reference?

Answer (score 9):

Don't use eval. Don't use dynamic variables.

If you have an unordered group of related data, store it in an object.

```
var myData = {};
myData[ newid + name ] = value;
```

although it looks like you are dealing with a dynamic object so

```
myData[ newid ] = myData[ newid ] || {};
myData[ newid ][ name ] = value;
```

Comment: it is valid to question the original intent, still this is not an answer to the question

Comment: @johannes_lalala — [Frame challenges are generally agreed to be valid answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263661/19068)

Comment: valid in the stackoverflow sense. I find it still more helpful to answer the question and, in case of fishyness, add a warning with a brief reason for the warning. Because even if you guess the context of the question right and not misjudge the knowledge of the OP, it is impossible to judge all context and intent of all who come here from google.