# obtaining z values of a circle in html4 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math, dom

[With an array of HTMLElementObject  with their corresponding property values]
[image: 1]
I obtain a circle by changing their x and y values as follows

```
<script>
 for(o=0;o<61;o++){
    eval('p'+o).style.top = Math.sin(o/9.6)*120+180;
    eval('p'+o).style.left = Math.cos(o/9.6)*120+180;
    eval('p'+o).innerText = '*';
  }
</script>
```

How can I rotate this object with given z properties like x and y?

Comment: o / 9.6 should be o / (Math.PI * 2) otherwise you are duplicating points

Comment: [Stop using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12268071/1048572). [Use `document.getElementById` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572)!

Comment: What do you mean by "*rotate this object with given z properties*"? Like making it look threedimensional?

Comment: Yes please, right now I can only edit x and y properties so it rotates in only twodimensional I would like it to do threedimensional rotations

Comment: #John you should use o/9.6 in both x and y if you are not sure try to:

Comment: #John you should use o/9.6 in both x and y if you are not sure try to: increase 9.6 to o/12.8 remember o has to be from 0 to 61. And you will then obtain a perfect Lissajous figure

Comment: #John but I have seen your point :)